# Use of enums in a readable way

Tags: java, enums

If I have the following static

```
private static String STATURDAY = "Saturday";
```

I can use that in a readable way:

```
myMethod(SATURDAY);
```

In this case an enum is better, for type security. However if I use an Enum, it's less readable:

```
myMethod(Week.SATURDAY.toString());
```

Is there a way to use enums in a readable way?

Comment: Can't the method accept the enum as parameter, like `myMethod(Week w)`?

Comment: code is for programmars to read and not for layman. Use whatever is logical.

Comment: Just as a side note, you *do* know that the `toString()` here will not return "Saturday", but "SATURDAY", right? (unless you overrode `toString()` in your enum declaration, which I really doubt). Thus, this is not perfectly equivalent to start with. Then of course, as others said, make your method accept the enum type rather than string.

Answer (score 8):

Make your methods receive enum values, rather than strings:

```
myMethod(Week.SATURDAY);
```

This should be why enum is usefull, because it avoids you all invalid string values by making them distinct in enum values.

Comment: In other words: this makes it type-safe, because there's no way you can pass an invalid value (a value that's not one of the enum constants - besides `null`).

Answer (score 4):

Besides making the method receive `enum` values as Kilanny says, you can use `import static` to import the enum constants, so that it looks exactly the same as when you were using strings:

```
import static com.mypackage.Week.*;

// ...

myMethod(SATURDAY);
```